# UTF8 encoding issue in scala

Tags: scala, maven, utf-8

I need help with the encoding to UTF-8. I am trying to populate few data in db using scala. I used the following code to convert the field to UTF-8.

```
def formatElement(value : String) : String = {
        var strValue = new String(java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, value.getBytes("UTF-8").length), "UTF-8");
        strValue;
    }
```

But the problem is the encoding done properly. For example:

```
Fülöpszállás getting saved as FÃ¼lÃ¶pszÃ¡llÃ¡s
Zablaće getting saved as ZablaÄe
```

I am using maven to compile and in pom.xml I have added

```
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

under "property" node

Comment: The problem can be in any of a number of places. Are you sure the data is stored incorrectly in the DB? The problem might be in when you read back and display the data. How are you displaying the output?

Comment: Your `formatElement` code does nothing - it takes a (UTF-16) string; converts it to UTF-8; then converts it back to a (UTF-16) string. Either the string is already corrupt or there is an issue with how you're populating the database.

Answer (score 0):

On analyzing the issue I have found out the reason. I have different file.encoding set in my websphere server. So the code is not required as the encoding is handled by the server itself. No matter in which format I encode my string it will get encoded to the format which is mentioned in the server. Thanks for your effort.